# Sum from spcific rows at sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wondering how can I retrieve sum data per "Product" from my table below:

```
  Status    Yield    step    lot          IN    OUT      Type     Product
Completed    100%    EDIS    Y6300510    173    173    SAMPLES    CANNON LAKE U X0 2+2
Completed    100%    LAB     Y6300510    173    173    SAMPLES    CANNON LAKE U X0 2+2
Completed    100%    EDIS    Y6300530     62     62    SAMPLES    CANNON LAKE U X0 2+2
Completed    100%    EDIS    Y6300530     62     62    SAMPLES    CANNON LAKE U X0 2+2
Completed    100%    LAB     Y6300530     62     62    SAMPLES    CANNON LAKE U X0 2+2
Completed     93%    TEST    Y6301020    165    155    SAMPLES    KABY LAKE U 2+2
Completed    100%    LAB     Y6301020    155    155    SAMPLES    KABY LAKE U 2+2
Completed     88%    TEST    Y6301050    168    148    SAMPLES    KABY LAKE U 2+2
Completed    100%    LAB     Y6301050    148    148    SAMPLES    KABY LAKE U 2+2
Completed     93%    TEST    Y6301070    169    158    SAMPLES    KABY LAKE U 2+2
```

Query results should give me the total of "IN" quantity from all "KABY LAKE U 2+2" products and write it under new column (if possible).
Then I will do the same for rest of my products.
Thanks,

I have some difficulties to edit my query to attached solutions.
my original query is:

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT vw_public_task.task_id,
ISNULL(task_state ,'Completed')Updated_task_status,
concat(cast(cast(step_out_quantity*100 as int ) / step_in_quantity as varchar(255) ), '%' ) as Yield,
 vw_public_task.task_type,
      vw_public_task.task_name,
      vw_public_task.vpo_number,
      vw_public_task.step_in_quantity,
      vw_public_task.step_out_quantity,
      vw_public_task.start_date,
      vw_public_task.complete_date,
      vw_public_test_steps_with_hold_count_z.vpo_type,
      vw_public_test_steps_with_hold_count_z.vpo_status,
      vw_public_test_steps_with_hold_count_z.product_name,
      vw_public_task_priority.task_state,   
      vw_public_task.operation_code

  FROM [vortex_hvc].[vortex_dbo].[vw_public_task]

   JOIN vw_public_test_steps_with_hold_count_z
  ON vw_public_task.vpo_number = vw_public_test_steps_with_hold_count_z.vpo_number

  LEFT JOIN vw_public_task_priority
  ON vw_public_task.task_id = vw_public_task_priority.task_id
 WHERE
 (( DateDiff(HH, vw_public_task.complete_date, getdate()) < 73) OR  (vw_public_task.start_date IS NULL AND vw_public_test_steps_with_hold_count_z.vpo_status NOT LIKE 'CLOSED') OR ( DateDiff(HH, vw_public_task.start_date, getdate()) < 73))
AND
 (vw_public_task_priority.task_state LIKE 'WIP' OR  vw_public_task_priority.task_state IS NULL OR vw_public_task_priority.task_state LIKE 'HOLD' )
 AND
(vw_public_test_steps_with_hold_count_z.vpo_type LIKE 'SAMPLES')
AND
(vw_public_task.vpo_number NOT LIKE '%CC' OR vw_public_task.vpo_number NOT LIKE '%CG' OR vw_public_task.vpo_number NOT LIKE '%ND')
AND
  (vw_public_task.task_name NOT LIKE 'ISSUE' )
 order by vpo_number
```

I'm not sure how should I edit it.

Comment: Show some sample expected output based on input data and also tag your version

Comment: Use spaces instead of <TAB> to get proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `GROUP BY` query *might* be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.inSum
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Product, SUM(IN) AS inSum
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Product
) t2
    ON t1.Product = t2.Product
```

On the other hand, if you actually wanted to update your original table, this would require more work.  You might not want to do that, if you think new information could be added to the table which would require that column to be recalculated.

Comment: @Coldfire No.  You should have put the query in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you cannot create group headers or footers. You will have to do this in some kind of reporting tool.

What you can do in SQL is to create a grouped query result containing only group summaries and group defining columns (`Product` here). But this query cannot contain all the details any more.

```
SELECT Product, SUM([IN]) AS TotalOfInQuantity
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Product
ORDER BY Product
```

You can also link this result back to the original table in order to output the product total on every product row:

```
SELECT MyTable.*, Totals.TotalOfInQuantity
FROM
    MyTable
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Product, SUM([IN]) AS TotalOfInQuantity
                FROM MyTable
                GROUP BY Product) Totals
        ON MyTable.Product = Totals.Product
ORDER BY Product, <other columns here>
```

Here, the grouping query is included in a sub-select (included in parentheses and named `Totals`), which can be joined just as if is it was another table.

Note also that "IN" is a reserved word in SQL. So you must escape it. In T-SQL (SQL-Server) and Access with `[IN]` in many other databases with `"IN"`.